# Index for roles in a script?

Tags: indexing

I am making multiple scripts for a project. There are basically 10 or so roles, and in each document, I want to have an index in the front of the document, after a table of contents, that has the page numbers for each role next to the name. Ideally, this would be formatted like a table:

| Role | Description | Pages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Role 1 | Foo | 1, 5, 10-11 |
| Role 2 | Bar | 2, 5, 10-11 |
| Role3 | Baz | 1, 7, 10-11, 21 |

I have tried using the `imakeidx` package with `\makeindex` and `\printindex`, and this works as expected with `\index{term}`. But, printing the index will only list the page numbers before `\printindex`. Like I said, I need it at the beginning because that is where the roles are. Further, I don't think there are the formatting options I am looking for in it.

Example of what I have currently:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

% PARTICIPANTS {as commands so I can reference them easily}
\newcommand{\celebrant}{\index{CEL}CEL }
\newcommand{\cantor}{\index{CANTOR}CANTOR }
\newcommand{\mco}{\index{MC1}MC1 }
\newcommand{\mct}{\index{MC2}MC2 }
\newcommand{\serveri}{\index{S1}S1 }
\newcommand{\serverii}{\index{S2}S2 }
\newcommand{\serveriii}{\index{S3}S3 }
\newcommand{\serveriv}{\index{S4}S4 }
\newcommand{\serverv}{\index{S5}S5 }
\newcommand{\servervi}{\index{S6}S6 }

\section{Participants}
% This is where I want the index-- I want page numbers of where these roles are in the document

        Celebrant (\celebrant): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Mast. of Cer. (\mco): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Cantor (\cantor): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Mast. of Cer. (\mct): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Server 1 (\serveri): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Crucifix, book\\
        Server 2 (\serverii): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Candle, paten\\
        Server 3 (\serveriii): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Candle, paten\\
        Server 4 (\serveriv): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Altar setup, bells\\
        \\
        Server 5 (\serverv): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\
        Altar setup\\
        Server 6 (\servervi): \underline{\makebox[1.8in][l]{}}\\

\section{Begin}
        Form the procession line with the help of \mct.
            The order is:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item \servervi with Thurible
                \item \serveri with Cross, \serverii and \serveriii with torches on each side
                \item All other altar servers
                \item \mct
                \item Gospel
                \item \mco
                \item \celebrant
            \end{enumerate}

\section{Section Two}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui minim labore adipisicing minim sint cillum sint consectetur cupidatat.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Any ideas? I was referencing the [Overleaf page for indices](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Indices) and did not find a solution.

Thanks!

Edit: fixed table format and added MWE

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! You mention you've tried a few things already—could you edit your question to share your code? If you could include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we could copy-paste, that could help somebody to address your question.

Comment: Don't have `imakeidx` generate the index as part of your compilation. Run `makeindex` or `xindy` or whatever separately. Then there's no problem printing the index first. All it does is input a file. You can do that whenever you want.

Comment: You will have to provide your own `.ist`  file to get the formatting the way you want. Indexing is structured in levels, in your case you only have main entries.  Suggestion first generate an index in a normal fashion, once you happy about the structure then develop the `.ist`   file.  Dont worry about the description at first as this is constant for each role and can be saved in macros say rolei@description{foo} .

Comment: What's the relationship between `Role1`, `Foo` and `Celebrant`, `\celebrant` and `CEL`? Presumably `Celebrant` is `Role1`. Then is `CEL` `Foo`? Or is the bit in parentheses in the first column of the table, too? I have an `.ist` to make a table, but I don't know what I'm trying to get into which column.

Comment: @cfr these are just in the table for an example of what it should look like. As to your question, `Celebrant` is the role title, ``\celebrant` is is a macro to add the abbreviation `CEL` to the document, with whatever formatting I need (bold, highlighted, index entry, etc.)

Comment: But where do the descriptions come in? What is `Foo` for `Celebrant`? I made something plausible-seeming up, but plausible-seeming-to-me may not be useful-seeming-to-TheSaltyPug ;).

Answer (score 3):

`imakeidx` creates the index file as part of the compilation and then reads it back in. As such, it has to be located after all `\index` commands have been issued. But that's not the standard case. Typically you create the index separately, just as you do the bibliography. Typesetting the index is then done on the next run by simply including the generated file. This means you can print the index at any point, just as you can the bibliography.

Here's an example with `makeidx` rather than `imakeidx`. Compile normally, then run `makeindex` and then recompile. You may need to repeat this to get all the page numbers correct as inserting the index changes all subsequent page numbers in the document.

This shows how to generate a tabular-style index with the information (I think!) you want. I'm a bit confused about the relationship between the output you show and the input you have, so I'm not certain how many distinct pieces of information there are for each individual role. I've assumed three (when role name and macro name coincide) or four (otherwise) and provide two commands for defining them.

- `\participant[<role name>]{<macro without backslash>}{<shorthand>}{<description>}`
- `\participants{<comma-separated list}` where each item in the list consists of three or four parts separated by `|`: `<macro name without backslash>|<shorthand>|<description>` or `<role name>|<macro name>|<shorthand>|<description>`. Elements may include commas if the elements are enclosed in curly brackets.
- `tabindex` is an environment used to produce the actual table. This currently has at least two problems.

  - First, it isn't the target output. That's just a question of formatting a table, so there are any number of questions you can use for that. Just adjust the definition of `tabindex`. You shouldn't need to fiddle with the `.ist`.
  - Second, it includes an ugly hack to eliminate a superfluous row. This may need adjusting if your font, spacing or `tabular` config changes.

The file will also spit out `roleindex.ist`, which is used to create the index with `makeindex -s roleindex.ist <filename>` before recompilation.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{roleindex.ist}
%% ref.: imakeindex.pdf 16
preamble "\n\\\begin{tabindex}{LLL}{\\\bfseries Role & \\\bfseries Description & \\\bfseries  Pages}"
postamble "\\\\\n\\\end{tabindex}\n" 
headings_flag 0
item_0 "\\\\\n"
delim_0 " & "
group_skip ""
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714141/ addaswyd o gwestiwn TheSaltyPug: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/714132/
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\sffamily}l}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeindex
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tabindex}{mm+b}
{%
  \section*{\indexname}%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{#1}
      \toprule 
      #2 \\
      \midrule
      \\[-5ex]
      #3
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \end{center}%
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq
\tl_new:N \l__rolesindex_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l__rolesindex_tmpb_tl
\tl_new:N \l__rolesindex_tmpc_tl
\tl_new:N \l__rolesindex_tmpd_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \rolesindex_participant:nnnn 
{
  \ExpandArgs {c} \NewDocumentCommand { #2 } {}  { \index {#1~(#3)~& ~#4} #3 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \participant   { O {\text_titlecase_all:n {#2}} m m m }
{
  \ExpandArgs {c} \NewDocumentCommand { #2 } {}  { \index {#1~(#3)~& ~#4} #3 }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \rolesindex_participant:nnnn { VVVV }
\NewDocumentCommand \participants { m }
{
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq { | } { ##1 }
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq \l__rolesindex_tmpd_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq \l__rolesindex_tmpc_tl
    \seq_if_empty:NTF \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq 
    {
      \tl_set_eq:NN \l__rolesindex_tmpb_tl \l__rolesindex_tmpd_tl
    }{
      \seq_pop_right:NN \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq \l__rolesindex_tmpb_tl    
    }
    \seq_if_empty:NTF \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq 
    {
      \tl_set:Ne \l__rolesindex_tmpa_tl { \text_titlecase_all:n { \l__rolesindex_tmpb_tl } }
    }{
      \seq_pop_right:NN \l__rolesindex_tmpa_seq \l__rolesindex_tmpa_tl
    }
    \rolesindex_participant:VVVV \l__rolesindex_tmpa_tl \l__rolesindex_tmpb_tl \l__rolesindex_tmpc_tl \l__rolesindex_tmpd_tl
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% PARTICIPANTS {as commands so I can reference them easily}
\participant{celebrant}{CEL}{Foo}
\participant[Mas.~of Cer.]{mco}{MC1}{Baz}
\participants{% equivalent to multiple uses of \participant
  cantor|CANTOR|Bar,
  Mas.~of Cer.|mct|MC2|Foo-Bar,
  Server 1|serveri|S1|{Crucifix, book},
  Server 2|serverii|S2|{Candle, paten},
  Server 3|serveriii|S3|,
  Server 4|serveriv|S4|{Altar setup, bells},
  Server 5|serverv|S5|{Altar setup},
  Server 6|servervi|S6|,
}
\renewcommand \indexname{Participants}
\begin{document}


\printindex

\section{Begin}
Form the procession line with the help of \mct.
The order is:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \servervi{} with Thurible
  \item \serveri{} with Cross, \serverii{} and \serveriii{} with torches on each side
  \item All other altar servers
  \item \mct{}
  \item Gospel
  \item \mco{}
  \item \celebrant{}
\end{enumerate}

\cantor{} is on vacation.

\section{Section Two}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui minim labore adipisicing minim sint cillum sint consectetur cupidatat.

\end{document}
```

Images of my output currently suck due to an Okular/KDE bug. My apologies.

[Attempted image deleted as worse than useless.]

Things I can't figure out:

- how to get rid of the spurious row inserted before the first index entry;

  - According to the manual page `item_0` is used between two top level items. Fine. The only problem is, it isn't just used there. It is also used before the first top level item and I cannot find a way to get rid of it.
- how to use any command starting with a `t` in the `.ist` file.

[image]

Comment: You will need a specal `.ist`  file to get the formatting right, Also modify the commands to  also store description. See my comments under the OP question.

Comment: @yannisl Yes, I know. However, I took the main point of this question to concern the timing. Anyway, the `.ist` isn't turning out to be as difficult as I expected. The manual page is pretty good ;).

Comment: It does get somewhat tricky if you also use hyperref

Comment: @yannisl That is definitely true. It also gets tricky if you need verbatim stuff in your index. And, yes, hyperlinked indices. Especially as there is no ready-made way to identify where things have gone wrong if anchors and targets don't match. (I'm told this isn't a problem for everyone else, but it is for me.)

Comment: Oh yes, is not a problem for Heiko! But for me I always scratch my head!

Comment: @yannisl Ulrike told me there was no option to generate information for debugging because it wasn't a problem. I assumed it was just me and made up some commands to get me information about where targets and links were. I'm sure it is unnecessary for Ulrike!

Comment: Added the image, works also miraculously with no extra work for hyperref  I just added `usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: @yannisl Thank-you!